# jQuery One Page and Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [jQuery One Page Nav Plugin](http://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav) with twitter bootstrap.

It is working fine. Linking to areas on the same page like this:

```
<li><a href="#section-4">Kontakt</a></li> works great.
```

But the problem is making links to other pages work. Nothing happens when I click the link:

```
<li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="navbar" id="top-nav">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
           <h1><a class="brand" href="index.html">Logo here</a></h1>
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav pull-right">

                        <li><a href="#section-2">Cv</a></li>

                        <li><a href="#section-3">Referancer</a></li>

                        <li><a href="#section-4">Kontakt</a></li>

                        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#top-nav').onePageNav({
            currentClass: 'active',
            changeHash: true,
            scrollSpeed: 1200
           });
```

Comment: Tried to use Js fiddel, but i have so much html/css/js. How can i do it easy ? The problem is only the main header above. What do you need more i will post that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to send the blog link to another page, blog.html.

You'll need to use the filter option to filter out this link, it is documented here: https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav#filter-example

HTML:

```
<li><a href="blog.html" class="external">Blog</a></li>
```

JS:

```
$('#top-nav').onePageNav({
    currentClass: 'active',
    changeHash: true,
    scrollSpeed: 1200,
    filter: ':not(.external)'
});
```